# Big(o) notation logn or n?

Tags: big-o

```
for(int i = 1; i < N; i = 2*i){

    for(j=0; j<i; j++){

    }
}
```

so I just learned that a logN for loop is one that either divides or multiplies in a statement, which the outerloop is doing. However, because the inner loop is incrementing with addition, and that linear time is a higher complexity than logN, would this for loop be considered O(n)?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, and is better suited for the Computer Science Stack Exchange.

Comment: Especially given that this really has **nothing** to do with a specific programming language. The above could be C, C++, whatnot.

Comment: sorry, figured programming time complexity had to do with programming

Comment: Let's say N is a power of 2. The loop iterates N + N/2 + N/4 + .... + 4 + 2 + 1 times. That number is 2N-1 (pretend that these are all bits in the number 0b111...1111), so the loop is O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner function is O(n) because it runs in linear time, and the outer function is O(log n) because i is multiplied by 2 every iteration. So to answer you question, yes the inner loop would be considered O(n) because j++ runs in linear time. But since O(n) is higher complexity than O(log n), then O(n) takes more precedence and the overall run time will be O(n).

Comment: I thought that big(O) would just take the higher of the two expressions and use that for it's time complexity?

Comment: You are correct, If I'm understanding your question correctly, are you asking if the inner loop considered O(n)? If so then yes it is an O(n). The outer expression is O(log n). But since O(n) is higher than O(log n) and the outer loop depends on the inner loop of O(n), then O(n) takes more precedence and the run time will be O(n). I will edit my answer because I didn't want to leave you hanging like the other guys that left comments

Comment: Thanks for the answer, id upvote you but I've been downvoted too many times lol